# Ruby how each loop is executed?

Tags: ruby, lambda

I have issue with technically deep question about loops in ruby.

I have algorithm that is executed sequentially for array of Boolean values and operate on one data structures.

```
def function(boolean, data_structure)
```

The key point is that the order of execution is most important thing because expression

```
 function(true, data_structure);function(true, data_structure); function(false, data_structure)
```

will leave other result in data structure than expression

```
 function(true, data_structure);function(false, data_structure); function(true, data_structure)
```

I spent some time trying with each loop, but I didn't get any problems as other result in data structure due execution similar expression as follow

```
[true, true, false ....].each do |value| function(value, data_structure) end
```

My question: in default ruby configuration is my each loop is the same like followed for loop?

```
for i in 0..array.size do function(array[i], data_structure) end
```

Because each loop makes the code much clearer and easier to modify and I was thinking about leave each expression rather than using for loop.
(Of course in my case I have a lot more code rather than calling only function()..)

Comment: Yes, `each` should iterate the array in order, the same as your `for` loop.

Comment: One way to check would be to `print` the values from the loop.  i.e. `[true, true, false].each do |value| print(value) end`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's identical. It will loop through the elements of the array, in order.

Comment: In fact, `for foo in bar` is just syntactic sugar for `bar.each do |foo|` — it literally calls `each` behind the scenes.

Comment: @Chuck, can you, meagar or someone else explain something for me? If Ruby uses `each` to implement `for loops`, how does it deal with the following: `for i in [1,2,3] do break if i == 2; end; puts "i = #{i}"`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland: You're right, that is a difference, so I guess "syntactic sugar" is a little bit overbroad. It is implemented with `each`, though. It's just that in one case the variable is parsed as a block argument (and thus scoped to the block) and the other way it's treated as a local variable of the method. If you want to see for yourself that it uses `each`, you can just do `Array.prepend(Module.new{def each() puts "Look ma, I'm called!"; super end})`. Then iterate an array any way you like and you'll get "Look ma, I'm called!" if it uses `each`.